# Warning : Method invocation getAssets may produce nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android

This is not duplicate question. I have searched in stackoverflow for same thing. I have located my font in Assets and using in my activity with below code

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), yatra.ttf);
```

its working fine but I am getting lint warning in getAssets() that it may produce null pointer exception. I am not able to find way to fix it. Let me know if someone have idea to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this code is executed in a `Fragment` - and Fragments `getActivity()` can return `null` if the fragment is not currently attached to a parent activity, thus you can get rid of the warning by checking if `getActivity() != null` before accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `getActivity()` may return `null`, so theoretically NPE may strike you if your fragment is not attached.